# MATLAB Coder and parfor in MATLAB R2014b

Tags: matlab, parfor, matlab-coder

Does the MATLAB Coder in MATLAB R2014b support `parfor`?

If I check [the documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html), it reports:

> Treated as a `for`-loop in a MATLAB Function block.

Does that mean that there is no speed improvement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Matlab Coder in Matlab-r2014b support parfor?

Yes, the list provided in you reference tells you it is supported.

> Does that mean that there is no speed reduction?

Yes. You literally quote "it is treated as a `for` loop".

So in the strict sense of the word `parfor` is supported, *since it will not throw an error*. However, it is treated the same way MATLAB would treat it when the parallellisation toolbox is not installed, as a regular `for` loop. Thus yes, you can compile MATLAB code containing `parfor` loops, but they will be treated as serial `for` loops.

Note that the above only holds true for function blocks; as @Edric pointed out:

> `parfor ...` ... creates a loop in a generated MEX function or in C/C++ code that runs in parallel on shared-memory multicore platforms.

Comment: Well, you basically stole my edit and changed 1 word. But yea, looks good now.

Comment: That is correct *only in the context of a "MATLAB Function Block"*.

Comment: @Edric thank you for the information. I included this in the answer as to make it complete.

Answer (score 4):

The loop runs in a serial manner only in the context of a ["MATLAB Function" block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)

If you check the MATLAB Coder `parfor` reference page:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/parfor.html

You can see this information:

> `parfor ...` ... creates a loop in a generated MEX function or in C/C++ code that runs in parallel on shared-memory multicore platforms.